# Smarty Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

I need to print this variable:

{$array}

And i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function write() {
    writing = document.getElementById('box_user');

    if(writing.innerHTML == ""){
        writing.innerHTML = "{$array}";
    }else{
        writing.innerHTML = "";
    }
}

</script>
```

When I click here, i dont get the result of the variable:

```
<td><button name="ver" onclick="write()"></td>
```

And the result must be here:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="box_user">
</div>
```

Content of variable:

```
 while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        if($tabla1 == ""){
            $tabla1 = "<table>
                        <thead>
                         <tr>
                            <td><strong>ID Formador</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Nombre</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Apellidos</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Teléfono</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>DNI</strong></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td><strong>".$array['ofca_idFormador']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_nombre']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_apellido1']." ".$array['daco_appelido2']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['usrs_mail']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_telefono']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_dni']."</strong></td>
                         </tr>";
        }else{
            $tabla1 .= "<tr>
                            <td><strong>".$array['ofca_idFormador']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_nombre']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_apellido1']." ".$array['daco_appelido2']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['usrs_mail']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_telefono']."</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>".$array['daco_dni']."</strong></td>
                         </tr>";
        }
    }

$tabla1 .= "</thead></table>";
```

I'm using a .tpl and all of controllers a model work great the problem is here.

I´m starting on smarty, this is my first project.

Comment: so whats happening now?

Comment: Isn't Smarty a PHP templating engine? PHP is server side, so you're not going to get PHP values in the browser at runtime with JavaScript, unless I'm missing something... You might want to look into some client-side JS libraries to accomplish what you want

Comment: Could you post the contents of the variable? I presume it's a PHP array, but for the life of me can't imagine why one would need to post an array as innerHTML... What is the expected output?

Comment: You can't use smarty like that. Also you didn't post any other code so we could provide an alternative. Smarty can send a response via php file if you did an ajax request, then you can just use Javascript to get the response and add it to the page.

Comment: You have the content of the variable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely familiar with Smarty, but I've done some PHP in my day, and I'll take a shot at an answer here. Forgive me if this answer is overly simplistic and sounds unnecessarily patronizing; I'm going to answer in a way that even a beginner could understand, since I don't know your skill level or familiarity with these concepts.

The main problem you're having has to do with the separation between the **server** and the **client**. PHP is a server-side language; JavaScript and HTML are client-side. The server is what hosts your website for the client, usually your web browser, to request and read.

The interaction usually goes something like this: your browser asks the server for a certain webpage, the server does some stuff to build that webpage up from the templates, and the server hands the completed webpage to your browser. From that point on, the server no longer has any access to your webpage, and server-side code won't do anything, because your browser doesn't know what it means, so if any server-side code is left as part of the webpage, it's just going to be rendered directly as text. Your browser *does* understand client-side code, however, and that will still work just fine.

Of course, sometimes you need information from the server after the page has loaded. The way your client-side code running in the browser gets new data from the server is generally through AJAX requests; essentially, the browser talks to the server again and asks for some data, the server again runs some server-side code to build up the data you're asking for, and it hands it back to the browser. This usually won't be in the form of another webpage, but will instead be in a data format like JSON or XML, which your client-side code can then process and use to add content to the page. But notice that the server-side code never touches the page; all it does is hand over some data that the *client-side code* can use to update the page.

If you're familiar with C and similar languages, think of PHP-style templates as preprocessor code. The preprocessor code can, in effect, add and remove sections of the C code at compile time, but once the build is complete, that preprocessor code doesn't exist anymore, and the preprocessor can't do anything at runtime; at that point it's all C. Similarly, PHP can build up client-side code, generate bits of HTML or JavaScript, etc., but once that page is handed off to the browser, PHP doesn't exist anymore as far as that page is concerned.

Based on the code I'm reading above, I think you have two options, depending on what you're trying to do. I can't quite tell whether you mean for that table code to be generated dynamically at runtime when the user requests it, based on some user input, or whether the table exists completely and is just waiting to be displayed.

1. If the table code already exists, I recommend moving it out of a PHP variable and into the page. If you don't want it to show immediately, you should use CSS to hide it initially and use that button click function to show it, something like this (assuming the Bootstrap `.invisible` class based on some other Bootstrap classes you used):

   ```
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="box_user">
     <div id="table-wrapper" class="invisible">{$tabla1}</div>
   </div>
   <script>
     function write(){
       document.getElementById('table-wrapper').classList.remove('invisible');
     }
   </script>
   ```
2. If you need to dynamically generate the table based on some user-generated info and MySQL queries, which it looks like you're using, then you have a little extra work to do. You need to look into how to set up a REST interface for your server, whether through PHP or something else, and you need to look into how to make AJAX calls. You should return data from the server as a JSON object, then convert that PHP code you're using to generate the table into a JavaScript function and pass in the JSON you get back.

Hope that helps! Please feel free to ask for any clarification you might need.